# Error : Cookies are blocked or not supported by your browser

Tags: multisite, cookies

I have a multisite WordPress installation. When I am logged in as a super admin from the main website, and go to the dashboard from the main site into another site, it asks me for login details. When I enter the details, it gives me an error:

> ERROR: Cookies are blocked or not supported by your browser. You must enable cookies to use WordPress.

I also added code in wp-config.php:

```
define('ADMIN_COOKIE_PATH', '/');
define('COOKIE_DOMAIN', '');
define('COOKIEPATH', '');
define('SITECOOKIEPATH', '');
```

Still the problem occurs, even though **cookies are already enabled**.

Answer (score 2):

Cookies are *enabled per default*. By setting

```
define('ADMIN_COOKIE_PATH', '/');
define('COOKIE_DOMAIN', '');
define('COOKIEPATH', '');
define('SITECOOKIEPATH', '');
```

you just *disabled* them by setting the path to an empty string. The `ADMIN_COOKIE_PATH` per default is the `SITECOOKIEPATH` followed by `wp-admin` and the `SITECOOKIEPATH` is extracted from `get_current_site()->path`. See [source](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/809baf442b0bd4aaedbbc06de8d6d14408a73d7b/wp-includes/ms-default-constants.php#L47-L82). Just revert what you did and delete the constants from your `wp-config.php`.

Your actual problem seems that your **browser** has cookies disabled. Better fix that :)